# Crontab - How do I name my backup file after a weekday?

Tags: cron

I'm currently running 5 identical cron jobs, one for each weekday, to back up my public_html folder on the Cpanel-based webserver. 
My cron looks like this:

```
tar -zcf /home/mywebsite/public_html/backups/monday_backup.tgz ./public_html
tar -zcf /home/mywebsite/public_html/backups/tuesday_backup.tgz ./public_html
.
.
tar -zcf /home/mywebsite/public_html/backups/friday_backup.tgz ./public_html
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to way to write the cronjob only once (instead of 5 times) so that the backup file automatically gets the weekday's name. Something like:

```
tar -zcf /home/mywebsite/public_html/backups/$weekday_backup.tgz ./public_html
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
tar -zcf /home/mywebsite/public_html/backups/`date +%A`_backup.tgz ./public_html
```

`date +%A` gives you the current weekday (try it in your shell or `man date` to see this and other options).

I never tried something like this (i.e. embedding a command) within cron line itself, so you might need to move it to a separate script and call that script instead.

Answer (score 0):

`date +%A` will give you the day of the week. You can pipe the output through `tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'` to convert it to lowercase if you want to match the names you are already using:

```
tar -zcf /home/mywebsite/public_html/backups/`date +%A | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`_backup.tgz ./public_html
```